# BUSQUEDA POR NOMBRE COMPLETO PHP Y SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Hola lo que pasa es que dentro de una base de datos tengo los campos Nombre,APELLIDO_PATERNO y APELLIDO_MATERNO en php lo que hago es buscar un dato:
por decir busco un solo nombre "Luis" y si me muestra toda la informacion pero si tengo mas de una persona con el mismo nombre tengo que agregar un apellido en este caso "Luis Martinez" pero ya no me realiza la busqueda y sale mensaje de que la persona no existe y no se que pueda ser, si alguien sabe de esto porfavor ayuda

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
$conexion = conexion();
$cont = 0;

//VERIFICA LA EXISTENCIA DEL ALUMNO
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM T.FCALUMNOS 
WHERE NOMBRE='$buscar' OR  APELLIDO_PATERNO='$buscar' OR APELLIDO_MATERNO='$buscar';";

try
{
$datos = $conexion->query($consulta);
$texto = "
<h1>DATOS DE ALUMNO</h1>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<thead>
  <th>
    CLAVE UNICA
  </th>
  <th>
    NOMBRE 
  </th>
  <th>
    APELLIDO PATERNO 
  </th>
  <th>
    APELLIDO MATERNO
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>";

$datos = $conexion->query($consulta);
while ( $fila = $datos->fetch() ){
$texto = $texto ."<tr>
<td>".$fila[1]."</td>
  <td>".$fila[2]."</td>
  <td>".$fila[3]."</td>
  <td>".$fila[4]."</td>

</tr>";
  $cont = $cont + 1;
 }
 $texto = $texto . "
 </tbody>
 </table><br><br>
 ";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
header("Location: index.html");
}

    if($cont!=0)
    {
      echo $texto;
    }
else{
  echo "<h1>EL ALUMNO NO EXISTE</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que estas usando no esta bien, para buscar por el nombre y el apellido puedes usar + así:

```
//VERIFICA LA EXISTENCIA DEL ALUMNO
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM T.FCALUMNOS 
WHERE NOMBRE='$buscar' OR  NOMBRE+' '+APELLIDO_PATERNO = '$buscar' OR NOMBRE+' '+APELLIDO_PATERNO+' '+APELLIDO_MATERNO = '$buscar';";
```

Comment: Hola, se me olvido comentar :'v uso una version antigua al parecer el CONCAT no sirve en mi sql por ser version antigua entonces no se que otro metodo pueda utilizar, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: que gestor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: @VictorA prueba con esta otra opción.

Comment: Utilizo microsoft sql server management studio 17 ya probe con esa nueva y nada sigue igual

Comment: @VictorA prueba esta otra.

Comment: Efectivamente amigo tube que hacer unos ajuste quedo asi :"SELECT * FROM T.FCALUMNOS 
WHERE (NOMBRE +' '+ APELLIDO_PATERNO +' '+ APELLIDO_MATERNO) LIKE '%$buscar%' OR CLAVE_UNICA='$buscar';